# If $P \iff Q$ is true and $P \land Q$ is false, do we arrive at a contradiction?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

> If $P \iff Q$ is true and $P \land Q$ is false, do we arrive at a contradiction?

So I know that $P$ is false and $Q$ is false.  And I also know that the biconditional $P \iff Q$ is equivalent to
$$\left(P \implies Q\right) \land \left(Q \implies P\right),$$
whence I do not arrive at a contradiction.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: If both $\;P,Q\;$ are false, then both $\;P\implies Q\,,\,\,Q\implies P\;$ are true, so what contradiction were you thinking about?

Comment: You could decompose things further, using that $P\implies Q$ actually means $\lnot P\lor Q$, hence $P \Longleftrightarrow Q$ means $(\lnot P\lor Q)\land(\lnot Q\lor P)$. On the other hand the negation of $P\land Q$ is $\lnot P\lor\lnot Q$, hence there is no contradiction since $(\lnot P\lor Q)\land(\lnot Q\lor P)\land(\lnot P\lor\lnot Q)=(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)$.

Comment: You are a bad guy if and only if you do bad things. Could it be that you are a nice guy after all (and that you do not do bad things)? I still have hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if both P and Q are false then these are both satisfied so I don't see any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well a contradiction would be if there is no possible value for $P$ and $Q$ such that both statements are true.

Since the statement is true if $P$ and $Q$ are both false, it is no contradiction.